cordova platform android gradle
enter image description here
after a lot of time trying download various gradle version
i get enough , don't know to start with cordova android
i run npm i -g cordova
cordova creat app && add android
when building its crushed
some time tell me target sdk: undefined
i success once time by helping  of android studio but the logcat keep typing in console unfitly, so stopped  the project
env:
in system
GRADLE_HOME  C:\Program Files\gradle-8.7-bin\gradle-8.7\bin
JAVA_HOME    C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr
ANDROID_HOME  C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
ANDROID_SDK_HOME C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
path:
    %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\emulator    %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\platform-tools    %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\tools\bin    %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\cmdline-tools\latest\bin    %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\tools   
 %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\build-tools   
 C:\Program Files\gradle-8.7-bin\gradle-8.7\bin

